# Issue with missing class DataEntry

Tags: java, import, processing

probably a very simple issue related to importing the correct libraries but I cannot seem to find anything to help me.

Basically getting this error when trying to run my code:

> "Cannot find a class or type named "DataEntry"

This is my Code here:

```
    //Variables
UnfoldingMap map;
List<Marker>countryMarkers;

HashMap<String, DataEntry> dataEntriesMap;

//Core methods...
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);

  //Read in GeoJSON File - Countries
  List<Feature> countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "countries.geo.json");
  countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
  map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);//Add the countries to the map

  //External Data source - CSV file
}


void draw() {
  map.draw();
}

//Other methods required...
```

This is a list of all my Imports

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.interactions.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.ui.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.core.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.texture.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.events.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.utils.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.*;
import processing.opengl.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

I am experimenting with GeoSpatial data using `Processing` and the `Unfolding` Map Library.

I'd appreciate any help guys.

Comment: If you don't know where this class comes from, neither do we. Look at the javadoc of the libraries you're using. And try to avoid importing complete packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely familiar with the packages you are using but based on examples I've seen, it seems as though you are missing an inner class.

Try updating the code as indicated below noting the `DateEntry` inner class at the very bottom:

```
//Variables
UnfoldingMap map;
List<Marker>countryMarkers;

HashMap<String, DataEntry> dataEntriesMap;

//Core methods...
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);

  //Read in GeoJSON File - Countries
  List<Feature> countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "countries.geo.json");
  countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
  map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);//Add the countries to the map

  //External Data source - CSV file
}


void draw() {
  map.draw();
}

public class DataEntry {
    String countryName;
    String id;
    Integer year;
    Float value;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, solved the issue for me thanks very much. Will accept answer in 5 mins when I can.